# Initialize internal object just once

Tags: scala

In Scala, I have the following class:

```
class A(param: String) {
  object B {
    lazy val db = {new D(param)}
  }
}
```

and then from client code I have to create class A objects multiple times but have the B.db parameter be initialized just once. Currently, this does not work as it will create a new instance of object B every time and instance of class A is created.

To add a bit of perspective, the B.db object is an instance of the Mongo class, which according to the documentation needs to be initialized just once. How would you go about it?

Answer (score 8):

put it in a companion object instead of an internal object

```
object A {
   apply(param:String) {
      new A             
   }

   lazy val db = {..}
}
class A{

}
```

Comment: damn...beat me to it by one minute^^

Comment: Thanks, this won't work though as class's A param needs to be accessed by the db object initialization code. Admittedly, the question was not clear enough.

Comment: you can add an apply in the object that accepts the parameter. I'll edit the reply to show that

Comment: I knew that, but you still cannot access param from the lazy val initialization code...

Comment: @GeorgiosGousios If you create `new A("1")`, `new A("2")`, etc., and just one `B`, which value of `param` should be used by `B`?